# Remove hamburger menu toggle when side menu open

Tags: ionic3

I have side-menu in my ionic 3 application and i have created custom icon inside side-menu to close menu but in ios it displays menu toggle when open side-menu but not in android. How can i remove this menu toggle in ios.

[image]

Comment: You can add `type="overlay"` to your `ion-menu`

Comment: Super this works awesome thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you click the menu call a function which sets a variable to true and put an *ngIf in the icon to hide it when that variable is true. As soon as you close the menu set that variable to false.

Comment: any alternative solution because its not showing in android. is it possible to overwrite anything.